# Showing $| \mathbb{N} | =|\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}|$ using the diagonal argument

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Showing $| \mathbb{N} | =|\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}|$ using the diagonal argument is seeming a little hard for me to prove by an explicit function.

It's clear that we need a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, and arranging them diagonally seems to work very well.

In other words:

$(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) ...$

$(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) ...$

$(2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) ...$

... (Not sure how to put in a table).

And we can say $f(0) = (0,0), f(1) = (0,1), f(2) = (1,0), f(3) = (0,2), f(4) = (1,1) ...$, going diagonally all the way through. I'm trying to find an explicit function for $f$ though. The most I've come up with is that:

$0$ maps to $(0,0)$

$1$ and $2$ get mapped to the points $(a,b)$ with $a,b \in \{ 0,1 \}$, and $a + b = 1$.

$3,4,$ and $5$ get mapped to points $(a,b)$ with $a,b \in \{ 0,1,2 \}$ and $a+b = 2$.

$6, 7, 8$, and $9$ get mapped to points $(a,b)$ with $a,b \in \{ 0,1,2,3 \}$ and $a + b = 3$.

How can we write an explicit formula for $f(n)?$

I'm aware there are many other ways to show these sets are the same, but I'd like to stick with this technique for now.

Thanks.

Comment: “Diagonal argument” usually has a different meaning in the context of cardinalities. Perhaps youmight want to call it the “zig-zag” argument or something like that...

Comment: Wikipedia: [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by a "formula," but your function has the following description.

$$f(m)=(m-t_n, n+t_n-m)\quad\text{for}\quad t_n\leq m<t_{n+1}.$$

Here, $t_n=0+1+\cdots+n$ denotes the $n$th triangular number.